# EF Core Include on multiple sub-level collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Consider this aggregate root...

```
class Contact 
{
    ICollection<ContactAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
    ICollection<ContactItem> Items { get; set; }
    ICollection<ContactEvent> Events { get; set; }
}
```

...which I have used like so...

```
class Person 
{
    Contact ContactDetails { get; set; }
}
```

How do I eager load all of the collections with the contact?

I tried this...

```
Context
    .Set<Person>()
    .Include(o => o.ContactDetails)
    .ThenInclude(o => o.Addresses)
    .ThenInclude(????)
    . ...
```

I've also tried this...

```
Context
    .Set<Business>()
    .Include(o => o.ContactDetails.Addresses)
    .Include(o => o.ContactDetails.Events)
    .Include(o => o.ContactDetails.Items)
```

*On a somewhat related note, is it possible to express what should be returned as part of an aggregate root using fluent configuration?*

Comment: @Igor, I've already seen the SO post, and tried the suggestions on the MSDN article...nothing working I'm afraid.

Comment: The ability to define aggregate roots is tracked by issue [#1985](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1985).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ThenInclude` pattern allows you to specify a path from the root to a **single** leaf, hence in order to specify a path to another leaf, you need to restart the process from the root by using the `Include` method and repeat that for each leaf.

For your sample it would be like this:

```
Context.Set<Person>()
    .Include(o => o.ContactDetails).ThenInclude(o => o.Addresses) // ContactDetails.Addresses 
    .Include(o => o.ContactDetails).ThenInclude(o => o.Items) // ContactDetails.Items
    .Include(o => o.ContactDetails).ThenInclude(o => o.Events) // ContactDetails.Events
    ...
```

**Reference:** [Loading Related Data - Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)