# .ThenInclude for sub entity in Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Previously (when using .net 4.5.2 and EF 6). I have had a generic `Get` method that accepted a number of includes as follows;

```
public abstract class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>, IDataContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    // reduced for brevity

    public T Get<T>(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return this.Set<T>().Include(includes).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

I would then call for example;

```
context.Get<Job>(id, 
    x => x.Equipment,
    x => x.Equipment.Select(y => y.Type));
```

To include the `Job.Equipment` and also the `Job.Equipment.Type`.

However, when I have ported this over to asp.net core 2. I have tried the same generic approach, but if I try to include a sub-entity I get the following error;

> The property expression 'x => {from Equipment y in x.Equipment select [y].Type}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Can anyone suggest how I can work around this to include sub entities in my Generic `Get<T>` method with Entity Framework Core 2?

**Update**

From looking at the documents there is an additional include method

`include(string navigationPropertyPath)`

I added the following method;

```
    public T Get<T>(int id, string[] includes) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        var result = this.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

        foreach(var include in includes)
        {
            result = result.Include(include);
        }

        return result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

Which does work, although I am not convinced on the efficiency here?

Comment: There's no `Include` overload that accepts an `Expression<Func<T, object>>[]` in Entity Framework Core, or is that how you use it in EF6?

Comment: `.Include` works correct, but it seemsthat selecting sub entities has changed in core 2? (the code that worked fine prviously no do not work). Also I found the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data which seems to suggest a `.ThenInclude`

Comment: Yes, you need to use `ThenInclude`, but your code does not even compile for me on EF Core 2

Comment: That's odd it compiling for me no problem. I edits to include my `DbContext` extension. I have noticed there is an `Include(string navigationPropertyPath)` which could possibly do the job. I'll give that a test and update with my results.

Comment: I can confirm using the above method does work. However, I am not sure on the efficiency of my method here? (i've updated the question to list it)

Comment: Efficiency is ok. Just the type safety (as with any `string`) is not.

Comment: @IvanStoev Do you recommend anything to try to cover on this?

Comment: Another solution is to convert the lambda expressions to a path as string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47063432/861716

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EF Core `Include` / `ThenInclude` pattern cannot be represented by `Expression<Func<T, object>>[]` like in EF6.

Looking at the source code of one of the EF Core extensions - [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#microsoftentityframeworkcoreunitofwork), which claims to be

> A plugin for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to support repository, unit of work patterns, and multiple database with distributed transaction supported.

looks like the intended pattern for includes should be based on `Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>>`:

```
public T Get<T>(int id, Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> include = null) where T : class, IEntity
{
    var result = this.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

    if (include != null)
        result = include(result);

    return result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

The drawback is that it adds EF Core dependency on the caller and requires `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`. Which in your case is not essential since you are extending the `DbContext`.

The usage with your example would be:

```
context.Get<Job>(id, q => q
    .Include(x => x.Equipment)
        .ThenInclude(y => y.Type));
```

Comment: Would this allow for multiple includes? for example if I need to include multiple  complex entities in a return? As with EF6 I could simple chain the includes to pull back what I need?

Comment: Yes, it does. In EF Core you would chain multiple `Include` / `ThenInclude`. Every `Include` is restarting from the root. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181872/ef-core-include-on-multiple-sub-level-collections/40185150#40185150) and in the documentation.

Comment: How do you think to make dynamic this? I would to have this in a BaseRepository thath is a base class of some repositories and 
I wouldn't write all the implementations for each repo, but I can't find a way to make the thenInclude dynamic, any suggestions?

Comment: @RSadocchi Not sure what you mean by "make dynamic", may be you could give an example. In the above example (and the link), the `Include` / `ThenInclude` is provided externally by the *caller* of the repo method.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for your answer, please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898559/how-to-make-dynamic-inclusion-of-navigation-properties for a code sample

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
   public abstract class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>, IDataContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        // reduced for brevity

        public T Get<T>(int id, Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> includes = null) where T : class, IEntity
        {
            IQueryable<T> queryable = this.Set<T>();

            if (includes != null)
            {
                queryable = includes(queryable);
            }

            return queryable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }

   context.Get<Job>(id, includes: source => source.Include(x => x.Equipment).ThenInclude(x => x.Type));
```